# ng-change get new value and original value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm using ng-options to select values from a pulldown. I'd like to be able to compare the old value to the new value. ng-change works well for grabbing the new value of the pull down, but how can I get both the new value and the original value?

```
<select ng-change="updateValue(user)" ng-model="user.id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users"></select>
```

For instance, let's say I wanted the controller to log, "Your former user.name was BILL, your current user name is PHILLIPE."

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909163/get-old-value-and-new-value-from-dropdown/28296355#28296355
might be duplicate

Comment: not sure how this works administratively but somehow the answers from the duplicate should be merged with this one.  bresleveloper is a nice solution (from the duplicate) but TGH answer should be shown as well.  The first relies on workings of framework, which could change in future, while the second is framework agnostic.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

With an angular {{expression}} you can add the old user or user.id value to the ng-change attribute as a literal string:

```
<select ng-change="updateValue(user, '{{user.id}}')" 
        ng-model="user.id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users">
</select>
```

On ngChange, the 1st argument to updateValue will be the new user value, the 2nd argument will be the literal that was formed when the select-tag was last updated by angular, with the old user.id value.

Comment: Note that the `user` in method call is the one from `ng-model`, and not from ng-options (may be misleading). Hopefully this elegant solution will work also in future versions of angular :)

Comment: This should be considered harmful. I just came across a dirty bug occuring when user.id contains a special character (like ' or /).This is because Angular expression parser does not like expression like updateValue(user, 'blah /blah').

Comment: In the function updateValue, $scope.user.id already contains the newly selected value - there is no need to pass a parameter for the new value to it

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka, I think it only works without the quotation marks if the `user.id` is numeric... it will not work if `user.id` is a string or a guid

Answer (score 17):

Also you can use

```
<select ng-change="updateValue(user, oldValue)"     
       ng-init="oldValue=0"
       ng-focus="oldValue=user.id"
       ng-model="user.id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users">
</select>
```

Comment: This answer works really well of ng-repeat. You can also use ng-click instead if the element you're using this on supports ng-change but not ng-focus.

Comment: ng-init="oldValue=0" & ng-focus="oldValue=user.id" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 16):

You can use something like ng-change=someMethod({{user.id}}).
By keeping your value in side {{expression}} it will evaluate expression in-line and gives you current value(value before ng-change method is called).

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="change(selectedValue, '{{selectedValue}}')">
```

Answer (score 15):

Just keep a currentValue variable in your controller that you update on every change. You can then compare that to the new value every time before you update it.'

The idea of using a watch is good as well, but I think a simple variable is the simplest and most logical solution.

Comment: Watch is little expensive operation , I liked the answer of db-inf .. it is simple working solution

Comment: Best answer. If you are inside a ng-repeat, create a variable in sub-scope using ng-init.

Comment: IMHO this is the best alternative. Since retrieving old values is not provided by ngChange out-of-the-box, solutions like the one from @db-inf might implode on future versions. Besides, this sounds like a controller's responsability, seems weird to delegate it to the view layer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a scope watch:

```
$scope.$watch('user', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // access new and old value here
  console.log("Your former user.name was "+oldValue.name+", you're current user name is "+newValue.name+".");
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: I have come across an article that states that watch is much more dirty/inefficient compared to ng-change. http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html

Comment: In my experience you almost never want to use a watch

Comment: If programming was a subjective art you might have something there. Alas - there are many reasons why you might want to avoid ng-charge or other directive based approaches, unrelated to doing things the "angular" way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a watch instead, because that has the old and new value, but then you're adding to the digest cycle.

I'd just keep a second variable in the controller and set that.

Comment: This is a pretty trivial example, I'd take readability over worrying about a single watcher in this instance. Still a good thing to be weary of I suppose.

Comment: Watch and ng-change actually have different behaviours: ng-change only detects user events, whereas `$watch` will fire every time the variable changes. Watchers increase complexity and are prone to creating update cycles when code changes their values.

Comment: I agree with @Rhys van der Waerden... this article states that $watch is a bit hazardous: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
... ng-model="file.PLIK_STATUS" ng-change="file.PLIK_STATUS = setFileStatus(file.PLIK_ID,file.PLIK_STATUS,'{{file.PLIK_STATUS}}')" ...
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.setFileStatus = function (plik_id, new_status, old_status) {
    var answer = confirm('Czy na pewno zmienić status dla pliku ?');
    if (answer) {
        podasysService.setFileStatus(plik_id, new_status).then(function (result) {
            return new_status;
        });
    }else{
        return old_status;
    }
};
```