# angular js ng-change not working

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I having a select dropdown angular js and new to angular js.
The code is:

```
<select class="required_input_mandatory inputs" ng-options="o.ID as o.OrganizationName for o in OrganizationModel track by o.ID" ng-model="OrganizationOption" ng-change="GetUsers()">
   <option value="">-Select-</option>
</select>
```

While the form is in edit mode, the HTML mark-up is

```
<select class="required_input_mandatory inputs ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" ng-options="o.ID as o.OrganizationName for o in OrganizationModel track by o.ID" ng-model="OrganizationOption" ng-change="GetUsers()">
<option value="" class="" >-Select-</option>
<option label="SHUK" value="1" selected="selected">SHUK</option>
<option label="SHAU" value="2">Cowshed</option>
<option label="SHNA" value="3">SHNA</option>
<option label="SHEUR" value="4">SHEUR</option>
</select>
```

And the GetUsers:

```
$scope.GetUsers = function() { 
    var uid = $scope.OrganizationOption; 
    var getUser = NotificationSettingsController.GetUserByOrganization(uid);    
    getUser.then(function (pl) { $scope.SourceUser = pl.data; }, function (errorPl) {
        console.log('Some Error in Getting Records.' + errorPl);
    }); 
}
```

Option "SHUK" gets selected. Now upon changing to other value, `GetUsers()` function gets called, but the option in the dropdown reverts back and makes the "-Select-" option selected.

How do I fix this?

Comment: could you add `GetUsers` method code?

Comment: $scope.GetUsers = function() {
var uid = $scope.OrganizationOption;
var getUser = NotificationSettingsController.GetUserByOrganization(uid);
            getUser.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.SourceUser = pl.data;
            }, function (errorPl) {
                console.log('Some Error in Getting Records.' + errorPl);
            });
        }

Answer (score 0):

HTML code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621104/ng-change-get-new-value-and-original-value):

```
<select class="required_input_mandatory inputs" ng-options="o.ID as o.OrganizationName for o in OrganizationModel track by o.ID" ng-model="OrganizationOption" ng-change="GetUsers(o)">
   <option value="">-Select-</option>
</select>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.GetUsers = function(orgOption) { 
    var uid = orgOption; 
    var getUser = NotificationSettingsController.GetUserByOrganization(uid); 
    getUser.then(function (pl) { 
        $scope.SourceUser = pl.data; 
    }, 
    function (errorPl) { 
        console.log('Some Error in Getting Records.' + errorPl); }); 
    });
}
```