# How can I have both the before and after values of an input field available in an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm new to AngularJS and am struggling with this, maybe somebody can help.

Let's say I have an input field with some initial value in it and I allow the user to change that value and click a submit button.  onbeforesave will give the value before it was changed and onaftersave will give the value after it was changed.  However, in the controller I need both the before and after values.  I can't figure out how to have both of them available to me in one function.  It's probably a simple thing to do but I just can't figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend looking at `ng-change` check this post, which I believe is similar to what you are looking for; [ng-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621104/ng-change-get-new-value-and-original-value)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a silly question..  still here is what you need

1. If you want a temporary value and user clicks in the textbox, it
   should be cleared. We call it **placeholder**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="click me here..."
```

2. Second, if your using angular may be you will be in need of the value in the text box in your controller so this would help.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var initialval=12; //initial value
  $scope.firstval=initialval;
  $scope.inputValue=initialval;
  
 
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" />
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Initial value</td>
      <td>{{firstval}}</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Changing value</td>
      <td>{{inputValue}}</td>
      </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you may have misunderstood the question, @metrangia want's to be able to see both the new model and the old. For example; current model; `dog` new model; `cat`, @metrangia wants to have access to both.

Comment: That looks right, although if there were, say multiple objects for example; user.id and the initial id's are required, ng-change would be a good bet!