# Angular Js - Reordering List Items

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a list which contains objects having sort order and country code property. You can change the sort order, now changing the sort order should reorder list items again as per the new sort orders. For example:

```
Country Code | Sort Order
AUS            1
IND            2
USA            3
UK             4
RUS            5
```

Now changing sort of UK as 2 should give result as :

```
Country Code | Sort Order
AUS            1
UK             2
IND            3
USA            4
RUS            5
```

I need a solution where the database changes should be minimum. Since this list would be send to C# web Api controllers via angular controller to save.

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Elaborate the expected database changes that you want to minimize.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. I changed only one value ie. changed UK's sort order from 4 to 2 and all other sort orders got incremented till USA's but RUS' remained same hence 4 became 2 and sort order 2 and 3 became 3 and 4 respectively. If I track scope.changes in angular then I will get three changes ie.UK, IND and USA. Is there any work around or minimal approach where I just need  to update only UK's record.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code provided, I assumed the UI code and workflow you are trying to work up. You can use the below code to selectively track changes to the model.

```
HTML:
<html>
        <input ng-change="change(ele, '{{ele.sortOrder}}')" type="number" ng-model="ele.sortOrder"></input>
</html>

JavaScript:
$scope.change = function(NewObject, OldSortOrder) {
$scope.NewObject = NewObject;
$scope.NewSortOrder = NewObject.sortOrder;
$scope.OldSortOrder = OldSortOrder;

//Make a call to the C# web Api now with the changes you want to update in the backend.
//$http.post('api/..');

}
```

The complete code is kept at https://plnkr.co/edit/LdhpZr?p=preview

Another query like this can be found at [ng-change get new value and original value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621104/ng-change-get-new-value-and-original-value).