# Getting the Current Value using angular ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, flask

I am trying to get the user selected value from select list using ng-change, but i can't seem to find what went wrong:

### Everytime i select any other option i get "Sam" , my question is how can i get the userselected value instead of the default one "Sam"

*Here is the html:*

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
<p>  Employee Name/Employee ID:
                <select ng-model="pickEmp" ng-change="setEmployee(pickEmp)">
                     <option ng-value="James">James</option>
                     <option ng-value="Sam">Sam</option>
                     <option ng-value="Patrick">Patrick</option>
                </select>
            </p>
</div>
</body>
```

*and here is the JS*

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.formObject = {
                         empId:'Sam',
                         que1:{
                            status:'YES',
                            payBand:0-11
                         }
$scope.setEmployee = function(){
    $scope.pickEmp = $scope.formObject.empId;

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-change get new value and original value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621104/ng-change-get-new-value-and-original-value)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `setEmployee` function, you are setting the ng-model as value `sam`. remove that line.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.formObject = {
                         empId:'Sam',
                         que1:{
                            status:'YES',
                            payBand:0-11
                         }}
$scope.setEmployee = function(){
   console.log($scope.pickEmp)

    }
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
<p>  Employee Name/Employee ID:
                <select ng-model="pickEmp" ng-change="setEmployee(pickEmp)">
                     <option ng-value="James">James</option>
                     <option ng-value="Sam">Sam</option>
                     <option ng-value="Patrick">Patrick</option>
                </select>
            </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but after deleting that i am getting key error

Comment: actually i am retreiving the user sumbitted values in a python script and after i delete the aforementioned line i get key error

Comment: bcoz in the json response the empId is missing after deletion

Comment: KeyError: 'empId' "POST /result HTTP/1.1" 500

Comment: Here is what i am doing to send data:

Comment: $scope.submitForm = function(){
    $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5011/result',
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.formObject)
});