# Getting the value of a dropdown before and after selection in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I am currently working for a project in which I am using angular. I have a drop-down field with the help of which I have to update the status in back-end. Is there any way to get the old value and current value of the drop-down field.

I already tried with 'OnChanges' interface and I couldn't achieve anything. Suggest some approach to get the value before and after selection is made.

Comment: Show the tried code

Comment: @NSSK while asking a question always provide what you have tried so far it helps in answering question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get old value and new value from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909163/get-old-value-and-new-value-from-dropdown)

Comment: @NikhilGangurde Since I am new, I am not aware of the exact process. I will follow your suggestion and will post the code from next time onwards. Thank you

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I will follow your suggestion and will post the code from next time onwards. Thank you

Comment: Glad to Help :-) @NSSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `FormControl` and bind it to the Template.

A `FormControl` instance has a `valueChanges` Observable on it that you can subscribe to, to get the currently selected value of that control.

But if you also want the previous value, then you can use the `pairwise` Rxjs Operator. Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  name = 'Angular';
  selectListValue: FormControl = new FormControl();
  options = [
    'Option 1',
    'Option 2',
    'Option 3',
    'Option 4',
  ];
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.selectListValue.valueChanges
      .pipe(pairwise())
      .subscribe(changes => console.log(changes));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<select [formControl]="selectListValue" name="" id="">
  <option value="">Please select an Option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

**PS**: It won't give you a value on the first selection as the default value of the `FormControl` is `undefined`. If you want the previous and the next value for the first time as well, assign a default value to the `FormControl`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You help me solve my problem with detailed explanation. Thank you